# PayPal SOAP API (.NET) - refund transaction error 10004 The transaction id is not valid

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using PayPal SOAP SDK for .NET to make a refund transaction.I try to call RefundTransaction method in SDK using transaction ID from SetExpressCheckout/DoExpressCheckout calls ( they work well ). PayPal API is returning 10004 error "Transaction id is not valid".
Here is my code:

```
PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService service = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService();
RefundTransactionRequestType refundTransactionRequest = new RefundTransactionRequestType();

refundTransactionRequest.TransactionID = transactionID;
refundTransactionRequest.PayerID = payerID;
refundTransactionRequest.InvoiceID = invoiceNumber;
refundTransactionRequest.RefundType = RefundType.FULL;
refundTransactionRequest.Amount = new BasicAmountType(GetPayPalCurrency(currencyID), amount.ToString("F"));
var request = new RefundTransactionReq() { RefundTransactionRequest = refundTransactionRequest };
RefundTransactionResponseType refundTransactionResponse = service.RefundTransaction(request);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check to make sure that you processed the DoExpressCheckout transaction as a sale and not an authorization.  If it was an authorization, you will not be able to refund it.  Also make sure you are using the transaction id that you received as the merchant, and not the transaction id you received as a buyer.  The two transaction id's will be different.  If you have checked both of these things and it still does not work, if you can provide the API response you are getting back that includes the TIMESTAMP and the CORRELATIONID I can take a look at it on my end.

Comment: Hi, the problem was I used buyer transaction ID, not seller one. When I used seller one which I found in PayPal seller transaction details on sandbox site, it worked! Thank you!

Comment: @PP_MTS_Chad : Hi i am using seller transaction id in paypal refund api but still it is showing this error

[TIMESTAMP] => 2016%2d06%2d22T14%3a07%3a11Z
[CORRELATIONID] => dd6fa4aaac3f4
[ACK] => Failure [VERSION] => 84
[BUILD] => 22998660
[L_ERRORCODE0] => 10007
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Permission denied
[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => You do not have permission to refund this transaction     
[L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error

Why is this happening ? I created a sandbox app and placed an order and then placed transaction id of seller in my paypal refund api script but it is showing this error ?

Comment: My CORRELATIONID is "dd6fa4aaac3f4"

Comment: FWIW - I just began receiving this error while trying to refund a transaction (in a live environment). I verified within my PayPal account that the ID exists. Is there a lag time for the PayPal Sale to actually become refundable?